# Objective-C ARC - Sharing Ownership

Tags: objective-c, casting, automatic-ref-counting

I really don't get bridged casts. I have the following code:

```
*value = (__bridge CppBridge*)_r->get_bridge();
```

Where CppBridge is an objective-c class and _r is a variable of type rb::typed_object which is a C++ class. The C++ class retains the object being returned from get_bridge()... Actually, I want to share ownership with the C++ class. In other words, I want both the Objective-C code and the C++ code add +1 to object so it will go to +2 retain count. And each one will go -1 at some point. What should I use? __bridge or __bridge_transfer?

Comment: Are you required to use either?  What happens if you remove the cast completely (assuming `get_bridge()` is declared as returning `CppBridge *`)?

Comment: I want to return void from the C++ class because I want the .h file to be used in pure C++ scenarios. But I may drop this requirement because it's so hard to understand this thing...

Comment: You could use a macro to "hide" the true return type unless the header is included in Objective-C:  `#ifdef __OBJC__ #define OBJTYPE CppBridge #else #define OBJTYPE void #endif`

Comment: Hmmm... Nice!!! I guess I'm going to do that. But for the sake of knowledge, I want to know how I should bridge between the Objective-C and C++ objects.

Comment: Well ideally the C++ should be Objective-C++ if you want the C++ to "retain" an Objective-C object.  For the other way around it doesn't matter (given C++ doesn't use reference counts).

Comment: Can I just store a Objective-C object in a field of a C++ class under ARC? Will it work?

Comment: Yes you can.  I personally would ignore the ownership issue within the C++ class and have all Objective-C objects owned elsewhere in Objective-C-land and simply treat the ownership like an `assign` property in the C++ classes.  Unless, of course, you are happy to change all relevant `.cpp` files to `.mm`, in which case they understand the ownership concept.

Comment: Just to add my $0.05: Indeed if you have Objective-C++, ARC will take care of you. If in some way you create ObjC objects in pure C++ somehow (e.g. by using CF methods) and you return a `void *`, you would do a simple `bridge` cast to create what you called "shared" ownership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I decided to use Objective-C++ and used trojanfoe solution. Many thanks!